# How to make dry ball pen work again?

Tags: repair, chemicals, work

I have a ball pen, nearly full (like 90%), but it is dry at the tip, and no ink will come out.

How can I make the ink flow again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have always just moistened the tip by licking it just a little and the making small circles on a piece of paper to get it rolling again.